# OSX doesn't list remote CUPS printer

Tags: networking, macos, printer, cups, multicast

I'm trying to add a remote printer in my OSX Catalina, but the problem is that remote printer is not in the list[image]

The remote printer is operating and properly configured, i used other OSX machine and iPhone to confirm that. So, seems the issue is with my OSX machine which doesn't list remote printer for some reason.

I noticed when i open "Add Printer" dialog a multicast request is being sent. So, i used `wiredshark` to confirm my machine gets multicast response properly.
[image: OSX receives multicast packets with printer info]

OK, since multicast packets are here, i've decided to run `dns-scan` tool to see what it received as well.

This is what i see on other machines in the network and this is expected:
[image]

but on my OSX machine i see nothing...

```
dns-sd -B  _ipp._tcp                            
Browsing for _ipp._tcp
DATE: ---Sat 24 Jul 2021---
10:28:11.362  ...STARTING...
```

Some misc things: IPv6 is disabled

### Now the question is

Where to dig next? Why OSX doesn't recognize multicast responses with printer info?

Answer (score 0):

So, finally, i've found what was root causing that. In my case a culprit was

**"Checkpoint Endpoint VPN 83.20"**

Irregardless whether you are connected or not to VPN, it still prevents multicast responses to reach out their recipients. So, helps only uninstalling.

Once i uninstalled VPN software `dns-sd` command started work correctly with response:

```
user@mac ~ % dns-sd -B  _ipp._tcp  local.
Browsing for _ipp._tcp.local.
DATE: ---Fri 13 Aug 2021---
13:44:26.312  ...STARTING...
Timestamp     A/R    Flags  if Domain               Service Type         Instance Name
13:44:26.313  Add        2   4 local.               _ipp._tcp.           Canon LBP2900 @ lbp2900
```

After i confirmed my printer gets resolved and successfully added to the system, i decided to re-install latest VPN of version 84.70 which looks working good, printer also gets resolved.

So, my summary is "Check Point End Point VPN" of version 83.20 has some issues or conflicts with the system somehow, such as system might suffer from multicast traffic blocking at some point.

On the other hand "Check Point End Point VPN" of version 84.70 worked good for me, it didn't block anything.